# Visual Studio 2022, detected ADB binary - no custom path to ADB

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, adb, settings

I'm trying to run a Xamarin project in an Android Emulator (Pixel 5 - API 30) for the first time in Visual Studio Community 2022, but I'm getting this error message:

> Detected ADB
> Could not automatically detect an ADB binary. Some emulator
> functionality will not work until a custom path to ADB is added. This
> can be done in Extended Controls (...) > Settings > General tab > 'Use
> detected ADB location'

[image: Detected ADB]

From: Tools > Options... - Xamarin - Android Settings

[image: Options... - Xamarin - Android Settings - SDK Location]
[image: Options... - Xamarin - Android Settings - Archives Location]

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?
And I don't know where to find the Extended Controls (...) > Settings...?

[image: Visual Studio Community 2022]

Comment: If you go to Tools -> Settings -> Xamarin all the way at the bottom, what is the Android SDK path there?

Comment: Android SDK Location: "D:\Android\android-sdk" and Archives Location: "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Archives"

Comment: And what did you set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable to?

Comment: I checked and I didn't have one.

Comment: I only have JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1"

Comment: Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Answer (score 3):

I think you should simply enable *Use Detected ADB*
I wish this could help you.

AVD setting
[image]